# Send Logs Buffer to remote pc

Tags: syslog, logs, systemd-journald

How can I simply read all the different buffers(system logs, user logs, applications logs etc.) of Ubuntu 16.04 and forward them to an external server (which could be any OS) in runtime?
Do any systemd or journal APIs help in this?

Please comment!

Comment: See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-remote.html for the systemd API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsyslogd` answer your needs.

[how-to-setup-remote-system-logging-with-rsyslog-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts](https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-setup-remote-system-logging-with-rsyslog-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)

> By default, there is an instance of `rsyslog` that runs inside every
>   new Ubuntu installation. The `rsyslog` tool takes care of receiving
>   all the log message from the kernel and operating system applications
>   and distributing them over files in `/var/log`.
>
> However, `rsyslog` can do much more than that which includes logging
>   into a remote server. This can be extremely useful for aggregating
>   logs across a large fleet of servers or when it is not possible to
>   write logs on disk.
>
> In this tutorial, we’re going to install `rsyslog` on a remote machine
>   so we can ship logs to, redirect all logging to that remote server.
>   Installing `rsyslog` on Remote Server
>
> You will need a copy of `rsyslog` running on a remote machine which
>   will be receiving the logs from your existing server. It’s best that
>   you have this in a remote location. The reason being that if this
>   server crashes at the same time as your server crashes, you won’t be
>   able to get any logs to troubleshoot any issues.
>
> Assuming that you’re using Ubuntu on the remote machine, you’ll
>   already be running `rsyslog.` If not, you can install it by following
>   the instructions provided inside the `rsyslog` website.
>
> Once it’s installed, you will need to make sure that it listens on a
>   port which we will send logs to. The default port is 514 which we’ll
>   keep. You will need to edit the file `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and uncomment
>   the following lines:
>
> ```
> # provides UDP syslog reception
> #$ModLoad imudp
> #$UDPServerRun 514
>
> # provides TCP syslog reception
> #$ModLoad imtcp
> #$InputTCPServerRun 514
> ```
>
> After uncommenting the lines, it should look like the following:
>
> ```
> # provides UDP syslog reception
> $ModLoad imudp
> $UDPServerRun 514
>
> # provides TCP syslog reception
> $ModLoad imtcp
> $InputTCPServerRun 514
> ```
>
> Once that’s done, you can now restart the `rsyslog` service by running
>   the command `service rsyslog restart`. Your `rsyslog` instance is now
>   ready to recieve logs from remote hosts. Setting Up `rsyslog` on Local
>   Server
>
> This process is extremely easy. All you need to do is tell the
>   existing `rsyslog` instance on your server to ship logs to your remote
>   server. It’s as easy as creating a file inside the `/etc/rsyslog.d`
>   folder called `10-rsyslog.conf`. Inside that file, all you need to put
>   is
>
> ```
> *.*   @remote.server:514
> ```
>
> Once you write that file, restart the `rsyslog` service by running
>   `service rsyslog restart` and your logs will now start being shipped
>   to your remote server. You can verify that by logging into the remote
>   server and checking the log folder, you’ll find that you now have logs
>   labeled with the hostname of the client server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read some features about journald, can we do this using it? I am now reading about rsyslog.

Comment: @AshishSultania - If my answer about `rsyslogd` answered your original question please accept it